# Postgresql cache and multiple import runs

Tags: postgresql, caching

I'm quite new to PostgreSQL. I'm implementing a c program to transfer much data into a PostgreSQL database.

In order to develop the program more and more I have to test a lot (especially performance), I have to perform several runs of the imports successively.

I want to make sure that the caches are clean again when I start the program again.

Which items do I have to keep in mind - besides shared buffers - in order to achieve this.

Thanks a lot in advance

EDIT:
We are using Suse Linux Enterprise 12 and PostgreSQL 9.4.

Comment: Try to be slightly more precise. Which OS your running? On Unix/linux like systems Postgres is also using comon system cache for disk opeartions. Didn't know how important it is for you.

Comment: "*I want to make sure that the caches are clean*" - why? They won't be "clean" in production either